# TapGesture added to UIView+SomeCategory. How can I use this UIView that is added to my UIViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, objective-c-category

I have a customized UIView. I've added a tapGestureRecognizer into this UIView. Not through UIViewController, but within the UIView+Category class. I'm trying to use presentViewController() when this UIView is tapped. This is a UIView class, it doesn't allow presentViewController(). I'm aware that only UIViewController allows this function to be called. So have I mistakenly architectured my project? Is it better if I just add tapGestureRecognizer to this UIView not using category but just straight off from UIViewController? This UIView is going to be used elsewhere as well so it would save me a lot of code if I can make this happen. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two straight ways to do that 1) Notification(provided example is written in ObjC) 2) Delegation(provided example is written in Swift)

1) Use NSNotificationCenter to inform the UIViewController that the view belongs to

In your UIView+Category where the gesture recognized handler is defined there, post notification and in your UIViewController add an Observer

In UIViewController

```
// Define it at the top of your view controller
#define kViewDidClick @"ViewDidClick"

 - (void)viewDidLoad {
     ...

     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]       
             addObserver: self 
                selector: @selector(presentVC:) 
                    name: kViewDidClick 
                  object: nil]; 
}

- (void)presentVC: (NSNotification *)notification {
    [self.presentViewController: vc animated: false completion: nil];
}
```

In your UIView+Category where you handle the gesture(for now I assume it's called handleGesture)

```
-(void) handleGesture: (UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: kViewDidClick object: nil];
}
```

2) you need to define a class that handle gesture and a protocol. This way you can handle all your gesture easily no need to define some methods in your UIView or UIViewController to handle gestures every time you want to handle gestures

GestureHandlerHelper.swift

```
import UIKit

/**
Handle gesture recognized by a UIView instance
*/

class GestureHandlerHelper {
var delegate: SelectionDelegate?

// MARK: Initializer
init(delegate: SelectionDelegate) {
    self.delegate = delegate
}

// MARK: Gesture Handler

/**
Handle gesture recognized by a UIView instance
*/
@objc func handleGesture(gestureRecongnizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    println(self)
    println(__FUNCTION__)
    println(gestureRecongnizer)

    if .Ended == gestureRecongnizer.state {
        if nil != delegate? {
            delegate?.didClick(gestureRecongnizer)
        }
    }
  }
}
```

SelectionDelegate.swift

```
/**
 Define a general rule for classes that handle gesture on views
 */
protocol SelectionDelegate {
    func didClick(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer)
}
```

In your UIViewController

```
class ViewController : UIViewController {
  ... 
  override func loadView() {
        self.view = View(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds,
          gestureHandlerHelper: GestureHandlerHelper(delegate: self))
  }
  ... 
}

extension ViewController : SelectionDelegate {

    func didClick(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        self.presentViewController(SomeViewController(), animated: false, completion: nil)
     }
}
```

In your UIView

```
init(frame: CGRect, gestureHandlerHelper: GestureHandlerHelper) {
      ... 
    var tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: gestureHandlerHelper, action: "handleGesture:")
      ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are approaching the problem from the wrong angle. It is important to follow good standards when implementing the [MVC, or Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pattern in your code. Think of UIViews as dumb objects that should only manage view layout code (and occasionally it's own custom animations). They should not manage ViewController logic as ViewController logic is outside of their scope. They are dumb and have no knowledge of anything that is not view related.

A better way to do what you want is to create a UIViewController subclass that manages your tap gestures for your view (you can add the tap gesture recogniser under viewDidLoad). Then subclass this ViewController from other view controllers when needed.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

To `presentViewController()`, you must need `UIViewController` object. i would like to suggest you, you can declare `UIView` as `UITableView` that is provided by Apple. Means you can create one `UIView` class and add `UITapGesture`, `Delegate` in that class. and `type cast` this class where ever you need like as `UITableView`(It may be from storyboard or programmatically).

Now declare one `Delegate` method in that created class. And Define this method to current `UIViewController` when ever needed. so now what happen, when you tapped on `UIView` it will called `UITapGesture selector` method.  in that selector method, with help of `delegate` method response transfer to current `UIViewController` class.

Now you can `presentUIViewController()` from current class.

So in this whole scenario, you need to just define `Delegate` method in current class without writing number of times same code in different class. this is same flow as Apple provided for `UITableView`.

[uiview-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-make-a-custom-uiview-in-ios-5-a-5-star-rating-view](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1768/uiview-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-make-a-custom-uiview-in-ios-5-a-5-star-rating-view)

This tutorial will help you to create custom `UIView`.
Hope this help you.

Answer (score -1):

If you want it that way then may be this can help you..
make a appdelegate object in your views class

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
AppDelegate *delegateObject = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

then

```
[delegateObject.window.rootViewController presentViewController:destinationControllerObject animated:YES completion:nil];
```

dirty way but will work.